# How to change the color of the tick in a Material Design Checkbox?

Tags: android, xml, checkbox, material-components-android

```
<com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
android:theme="@style/CheckBoxTheme"
/>
```

This is the checkbox

[image]

This is the `style`.

```
<style name="CheckBoxTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFC107</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#9C27B0</item>
</style>
```

I want to have a blue colour tick inside, without changing the background of the text + box

I tried

```
<com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
android:theme="@style/CheckBoxTheme"
android:background="@color/blue_banner_bg"
/>
```

yet what I get is this

[image]

what should I do?

Comment: Add `android:buttonTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"` this line in your `xml` file

Comment: @Dinesh I only want to change the tick colour, nothing more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use custom icon for your `CheckBox`. It should be a `selector` drawable like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- unchecked -->
    <item android:state_checked="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_checked" /> <!-- checked -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Drawables `button_checked` and `button_normal` should be defined by you.

Then use this drawable like this

```
<com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
    android:theme="@style/CheckBoxTheme"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
/>
```

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank it help a bit

Comment: Using the above approach will result in losing the Material Check Box state-changing animation. Also in case of dark theme it will not work as expected

Comment: @Muhammadwaris if you would do everything correctly - it will have a material effect and will work during the theme change. You will have to adjust some things, but the question was not about that so I didn't include it in the answer. You are free to edit with those additions, though.